# "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console

Tags: javascript, php

model

```
$geocode_stats = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$placename&sensor=false");
```

Note:- When i execute it,i got this :-

> "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend
>   registering for a key at the Google Developers Console

Comment: two things:- check in the Google developer console what limit is applied for that api call , change that limit, or check is that api have any registered ip, if yes then either remove it or add your ip there and try.

Comment: m not apply any limit in this code

Comment: I am not talking about code. I am talking about go to your Google developer account where you have this API and check there

Answer (score 0):

provide a key in your link as google Doc says....
like this below :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
```